# Excel IF function for three conditions (2 x number, 1 x text) and two outcomes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column which has positive numbers, negative numbers and a text statement "No Responses.". If the number is positive I would like "yes" to be the outcome in a new column, if it is negative or the text 'No Responses." I would like the outcome to be "no" in a new column. I have tried the following:

```
=IF(E2<0, "no", IF(E2="No Responses.", "no", "yes"))
```

However, I still get "yes" for "No Responses.". Does anyone have a solution.

Comment: Check for exact match, it should be exactly as "No Responses." as yu have mentioned in formula else it will give you result as "Yes".

Comment: It is an exact match. I wondered if the full stop in that condition is causing a problem.

Comment: Yes, Your "E2" cell should include full stop too in order to match with the formula.

Comment: Strange, I just tested your formula and It works for me. Have you tried using ";" instead of "," - that depends from which country you are though. And you don't have no IF for blank cell, is that OK ?....=IF(E2<0;"no";IF(E2="No Responses";"no";"yes"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to avoid any string comparison issues

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(E2), IF(E2>0, "yes", "no"), "no")
```

This way only positive numbers will give a "yes" anything else is "no"

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula.

```
=IF(E2="No Responses.","No",IF(E2>0,"Yes","No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ISNUMBER` function to check if you are dealing with text or numbers. Then you can use a second, nested `IF` statement to check the value of the number. E.g.:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A3),IF(A3<0,"no","yes"),"no")
```